# Array.Exist() only recognizing last element of an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I apologize if this is an obvious answer, but I couldn't find anything related to this behavior on StackOverflow nor on Google. I'm self-teaching c# and am writing a program that involves the use of username/password pairs. In this case, I am using `.Exist()` to determine if a username is already in my array of usernames.

```
    static bool LookUpS(string targ, string[] arr)
    {
        if (Array.Exists(arr, e => e == targ))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The argument `targ` comes from the user, and the argument `arr` is written into the program to specify which array should be searched (this is so that I can use `LookUpS` on different arrays). The array that I'm testing right now is derived from a text document. I've tested to confirm that the transition from .txt to array is working properly.

Now to the actual issue. I've filled the text document in question with a few values: "Jupiter", "Neptune", "Saturn", "Mars". If I pass any of the first three into `LookUpS`, it returns `false` despite the fact that they do exist. The part I don't understand, however, is that if I pass "Mars" (or whatever the last value happens to be) into the function, it returns `true` like it should. If I were to remove the "Mars" value, `LookUpS` would say that "Saturn" is `true` but not the others. Can anyone offer some explanation for this? I can post a more complete picture of the program if that would help in identifying the problem.

Comment: Have you placed a breakpoint inside the `Exists` delegate to debug each value in the array as it is iterated over?

Comment: How do you convert the .txt file into an array? It could be that the strings in `arr` contain a newline character, except for the last one.

Comment: I'll say that there is a problem with the splitting of the strings. Try printing `string.Join("|", arr)` and see if there are spaces around the `|`.

Comment: I read the txt file into a string then split the string with .Split(new char[] { '\n' }); It does seem like the "\n" would explain why this is happening, but I was under the impression that the split character wouldn't be included in the array.

Comment: @AlexClough The split character would not, but tif the file is broken by `\r\n` pairs then the `\r` _would_ remain.  Try using `ReadAllLines` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments you mention that you split the lines with \n as split separator. But on Windows \r\n is used. Hence your split string array will contain

- xxxx\r
- yyyy\r
- lastUser

The last line does not contain a newline which will work.

That explains why your search in the array finds only the last user in your array. Pass to the split operation not \r but Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray() to remove all newline characters in string array.

Comment: Thank you! I should have realized that because when I iterated over the array, the carriage returned but the line didn't change. I thought that was a byproduct of .Write(). I also took the advice of Malte R, and everything is working smoothly.

Comment: Instead of splitting on `Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray()` as you suggest, he could use a different overload and split on `new[] { Environment.NewLine }`.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays have a [built-in method called `contains()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384015%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which should do exactly what you want...

```
string[] array = { "Jupiter", "Neptune", "Saturn", "Mars" };
if (array.Contains("Neptune")) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't explain why the existing code doesn't work - while `Contains` is simpler, I would expect the original code to work if this would.

Comment: I have now tried using contains and it still doesn't work. Likely because Glorfindel is correct about the \n.

Comment: In that case it would seem that the issue here is your input data and not the methods you are using to test it. The best thing to do here would be to iterate over the contents of the array(or debug it) and find out what the actual values are.

Comment: Using a for loop and Console.Write(array[i]) I iterated over it. The cursor never changed lines which I would think means that there is no newline character in the elements.

Comment: There is no method `Contains` in `System.Array`. You can either call an explicit interface implementation, as in `((ICollection<string>)array).Contains("Neptune")`, or use Linq which has an extension [`Enumerable.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx). The latter might short-cut and call the former when possible (could be an advantage with hash tables and sorted dictionaries, for example).

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify it to something like this.
You can use Exists() instead of Any() if you like.

```
static bool LookUpS(string targ, string[] arr)
    {
        return (arr.Any(s => s == targ))
    }
```

Or if you want it to be non case-sensitive:

```
static bool LookUpS(string targ, string[] arr)
    {
        return (arr.Any(e => String.Equals(e, targ, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
    }
```

Or, as Karl suggests, you can use Contains()

```
static bool LookUpS(string targ, string[] arr)
        {
            return (arr.Contains(targ);
        }
```

Sometimes simplifying your code can solve some problems :)

The reason that you don't need to use an `if .. else` to return `true` or `false`, is that the methods Any(), Exists() and Contains() return are bool, so you can just return the method call as shown in the examples

Comment: I can't see why your current code shouldn't work, but perhaps this can help you.